# Error handling in TCL

Tags: error-handling, tcl

I have a following procedure:

```
proc show_information {args} {
set mandatory_args {
        -tftp_server
        -device ANY
        -interface ANY

}
set optional_args {
        -vlan ANY

}

parse_dashed_args -args $args -optional_args $optional_args -mandatory_args $mandatory_args

log -info "Logged in device is: $device"
log -info "Executing proc to get all data"
set commands {
              "show mpls ldp neighbor"
              "show mpls discovery vpn"
              "show mpls interface"
              "show mpls ip binding"
              "show running-config"
              "show policy-map interface $intr vlan $vlan input"
              "show run interface $intr
            }

foreach command $commands {
    set show [$device exec $command]
    ats_log -info $show

  }
 }
```

I am new to tcl and wants to know how can we handle error if anyhow we pass wrong parameter or it errors out.
Something like python try *(executes the proc) and except *(prints some msg in case of failure) in TCL.

After some googling 'catch' is what is used in TCL but not able to figure out how can I use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `catch` command runs a script and catches any failures in it. The result of the command is effectively a boolean that describes whether an error occurred (it's actually a result code, but 0 is success and 1 is error; there are a few others but you won't normally encounter them). You can also give a variable into which the “result” is placed, which is the normal result on success and the error message on failure.

```
set code [catch {
    DoSomethingThat mightFail here
} result]

if {$code == 0} {
    puts "Result was $result"
} elseif {$code == 1} {
    puts "Error happened with message: $result"
} else {
    # Consult the manual for the other cases if you care
    puts "Code: $code\nResult:$result"
}
```

In many simple cases, you can shorten that to:

```
if {[catch {
    DoSomethingThat mightFail here
} result]} {
    # Handle the error
} else {
    # Use the result
}
```

Tcl 8.6 added a new command for handling errors though. The `try` command  is rather more like what you're used to with Python:

```
try {
    DoSomethingThat mightFail here
} on error {msg} {
    # Handle the error
}
```

It also supports `finally` and `trap` clauses for guaranteed actions and more sophisticated error handling respectively. For example (something which it is annoying to write with `catch`):

```
try {
    DoSomethingThat mightFail here
} trap POSIX {msg} {
    # Handle an error from the operating system
}
```

Comment: Thanks Donal (please correct if wrong):

    try {
        show_information {some arguments}
    }  {
        print "check your arguments"
    }

Comment: `try {
    show_information {some arguments}
} on error {msg} {
    # Handle the error
puts "Error $msg"
}`

Comment: I think better use `error` to trow errors. Or `return` has additional parameters for that. `return -code error "my error"`